# Ansible - 'Undefined' at beginning and end of Key when map'ing a Attribute

Tags: filter, ansible, yaml, jinja2

When map'ing a attribute in a list of variables, Ansible is adding a 'Undefined' to the beginning and end of the key.

The variables:

```
vault_config_listener_params:
  - address: "0.0.0.0:8200"
  - tls_cert_file: "/etc/ssl/certs/wildcard.crt"
  - tls_key_file: "/etc/ssl/certs/wildcard.key"
```

The debug task:

```
- debug: var=vault_config_listener_params|map(attribute="tls_cert_file")|list
```

The output:

```
ok: [id70118] => {
    "vault_config_listener_params|map(attribute=\"tls_cert_file\")|list":
"[Undefined, u'/etc/ssl/certs/wildcard.crt', Undefined]"
}
```

The maping seems to have worked, as the key path has been extracted. But where are the 'Undefined' coming from?

*PS: The variables needs to be a list, as they are looped it in another place with jinja2.*

Comment: Used with Ansible 2.3.1.0 & Python 2.7.13

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, don't use `debug`'s `var` when printing arbitrary expressions, use `msg` instead.

As for your question, `map` is quite dumb and doesn't do what you don't ask it to, so you actually need to select items with specified attributes defined first, and then get its values:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ vault_config_listener_params | selectattr('tls_cert_file','defined') | map(attribute='tls_cert_file') | list }}"
```

Comment: Cheers mate!

    "msg": [
        "/etc/ssl/certs/wildcard.laterooms.io.crt"
    ]

That was how i want it!